# How do I programmatically display a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios

I'm looking at an iPhone application, with several ViewControllers controlled by a UINavigationController.

Somewhere deep down one of the ViewControllers is creating a view, and the view is trying to pop a

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl
```

up on top of itself like so:

```
[self.window addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

"self" is a specialized form of UIView, and the control's frame is set

```
 segmentedControl.frame = someFrame;
```

For some reason, the control is not showing up on top of the current view. Should this work, and, if it should, what are the most likely causes of trouble?

Comment: Do you mean a UINavigationController instead of NavigationViewController? If so, does it should be controlling UIViewController, not UIViews.

Comment: Show where you actually created the segment.

Comment: Also, what kind of object is self.window? Where is it positioned? Where is the UISegmentedControl positioned in relation to the specialized view you are talking about? Show us more code please.

Comment: self.window is a UIWindow (probably the same as [AppDelegate window]) - would be weird if it was something else? Could this be an issue with the view trying to pop the control?

Comment: Are you loading said custom UIView from a xib or storyboard? Or creating it programmatically, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `self` is a specialized form of UIView I'm guessing you are referring to a UIView custom subclass.

If you are adding the UISegmentedControl from within this view, you want to do the following:

```
[self addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

You set it's frame relative to it's superview, so if you want it on the top left corner you would do:

```
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, someWidth, someHeight);
```

Comment: There were two bugs, your answer caused me to fix both: the frame was set (almost entirely) outside of the visible portion of the screen, and the segmented control was (probably) not ending up on top of the view.